# Why is my VScode C compiler not working like it used to?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, mingw, homebrew

I have been learning C for a month now and I've been using VScode on mac to do it. I followed the following video(i.e by installing homebrew and mingw and installing extentions in VScode) and it ran exactly as shown in the video.

video---->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhGnYWplLVo i.e it automatically opened a .json file after debugging.

I went to my class in the morning and it ran fine, but when I reached home and tried to run a program, it did not compile.

- I used to f5(shortcut to debug) and a drop down menu popped which had GDB/LLDB and Microsoft. I used to click the GDB and it opened a .json file. I then ran the program and it would normally run in the terminal. But this time, there was a second popup after clicking GDB:-

-**C/C++:gcc build and debug active file** prelaunchTask C/C++:gcc build active file  Detected task

-after clicking this option the following would appear and had to be closed several times one after another. This had never happened before::-
[Developer tools access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Tuz.png)

And after doing this the following would be shown in vscode, and the .json file would not open:--
[Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fcz5.jpg)

The only thing I did after my class was download epic games launcher and a game from there.

Can anyone help me so that it can work again like it used to(as shown in video mentioned above).
Thanks a lot, this has been stressing me out a lot.

Comment: why did you tag C++ but not C ?

Comment: ***it did not compile*** Compiling is controlled by what you have in your `tasks.json` Debugging is controlled by your `launch.json`

Comment: sorry, mb, i changed it

Comment: @drescherjm how do i and where do i check both the tasks.json and launch.json so that it will work again. Sorry I am new to  C, Mac and VScode

Comment: These files should be in your .vscode folder. And they are described by the documentation: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) with that said I am not sure what steps you are doing to support mingw on macOS. I don't develop on macOS.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you for this. I have been looking everywhere not knowing what to do. I will check it. Even I dont really understand it but I just followed the video and went with it. If there is anyone you know using VScode on Mac, could you tell them to share their views on this. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you may now be getting a different compiler toolchain than you did before -- the XCode command-line tools, for example, instead of the tools you installed from homebrew (and mingw?).  This may have arisen because you installed something else that brought in the Apple developer tools as a dependency. I recently had exactly that happen when I installed git, but I do not use VSCode, so I can't say what effects that could have had in that area.

Comment: @JohnBollinger YESSS! I am also thinking if this might be the problem. I had installed Epic games launcher which might be similar to your case. Before, it did not show anything below GDB but now it says gcc build active. How to I tur it back? Thanks!